# Why does angular inject the wrong object upon using derived class

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-material

I'm trying to create a material mat-tab-nav with a vertical option in Angular 16. I've done this before for Angular 14, which worked fine, but was also very different.

So I've created a library with derived classes of each MatTabNav (the container element) and MatTabLink (the actual tabs). The former basically just adds a class "mat-vertical" or "mat-horizontal" based on the orientation attribute passed to style the layout. The latter contains a function that recalculates the ink bar's position to place it next to the active tab.

This is the container component, which also passes the orientation to the tabs, so the user won't have to manually add the orientation to both container and tabs. The @Component is mostly a copy of the original MatTabNav component besides changed selector, exportAs and added providers and the orientation classes. Both template and style files are mere copies of MatTabNav's.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[mat-oriented-nav-bar]',
  exportAs: 'matOrientedNavBar, matOrientedNav',
  inputs: ['color'],
  templateUrl: 'mat-oriented-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['mat-oriented-nav.component.scss'],
  host: {
    '[attr.role]': '_getRole()',
    'class': 'mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar mat-mdc-tab-header',
    '[class.mat-mdc-tab-header-pagination-controls-enabled]': '_showPaginationControls',
    '[class.mat-mdc-tab-header-rtl]': "_getLayoutDirection() == 'rtl'",
    '[class.mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar-stretch-tabs]': 'stretchTabs',
    '[class.mat-primary]': 'color !== "warn" && color !== "accent"',
    '[class.mat-accent]': 'color === "accent"',
    '[class.mat-warn]': 'color === "warn"',
    '[class.mat-horizontal]': 'orientation === "horizontal"',
    '[class.mat-vertical]': 'orientation === "vertical"',
    '[class._mat-animation-noopable]': '_animationMode === "NoopAnimations"',
    '[style.--mat-tab-animation-duration]': 'animationDuration'
  },
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  // tslint:disable-next-line:validate-decorators
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
  providers: [{ provide: MatTabNav, useExisting: MatOrientedNav }]
})
export class MatOrientedNav extends MatTabNav implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() orientation: Orientation;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef,
              @Optional() dir: Directionality,
              ngZone: NgZone,
              changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
              viewportRuler: ViewportRuler,
              platform: Platform,
              @Optional() @Inject(ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE) animationMode?: string,
              @Optional() @Inject(MAT_TABS_CONFIG) defaultConfig?: MatTabsConfig) {
    super(elementRef, dir, ngZone, changeDetectorRef, viewportRuler, platform, animationMode, defaultConfig);

    this.orientation = 'horizontal';
  }

  override ngAfterContentInit() {
    super.ngAfterContentInit();

    this._items.forEach((item: MatTabLink) => (item as MatOrientedLink).orientation = this.orientation);
  }
}
```

The link bar also only has one changed function, which now sets either width and left or height and top of the native element depending on orientation, instead of always width and left.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[mat-oriented-link], [matOrientedLink]',
  exportAs: 'matOrientedLink',
  inputs: ['disabled', 'disableRipple', 'tabIndex', 'active', 'id'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './mat-oriented-link.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mat-oriented-link.component.scss'],
  host: {
    'class': 'mdc-tab mat-mdc-tab-link mat-mdc-focus-indicator',
    '[attr.aria-controls]': '_getAriaControls()',
    '[attr.aria-current]': '_getAriaCurrent()',
    '[attr.aria-disabled]': 'disabled',
    '[attr.aria-selected]': '_getAriaSelected()',
    '[attr.id]': 'id',
    '[attr.tabIndex]': '_getTabIndex()',
    '[attr.role]': '_getRole()',
    '[class.mat-mdc-tab-disabled]': 'disabled',
    '[class.mdc-tab--active]': 'active',
    '(focus)': '_handleFocus()',
    '(keydown)': '_handleKeydown($event)'
  },
  providers: [{ provide: MatTabLink, useExisting: MatOrientedLink }],
})
export class MatOrientedLink extends MatTabLink {
  constructor(tabNavBar: MatOrientedNav,
              override elementRef: ElementRef,
              @Optional() @Inject(MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS) globalRippleOptions: RippleGlobalOptions | null,
              @Attribute('tabindex') tabIndex: string,
              focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
              @Optional() @Inject(ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE) animationMode?: string) {
    super(tabNavBar, elementRef, globalRippleOptions, tabIndex, focusMonitor, animationMode);
  }

  private _inkBarContentElement!: HTMLElement | null;

  /** Aligns the ink bar to the current item. */
  override activateInkBar(previousIndicatorClientRect?: ClientRect) {
    const element: HTMLElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;

    // const inkBarContentElement = element.querySelector('.mdc-tab-indicator__content.mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline');

    // Early exit if no indicator is present to handle cases where an indicator
    // may be activated without a prior indicator state
    if (
      !previousIndicatorClientRect ||
      !element.getBoundingClientRect ||
      !this._inkBarContentElement
    ) {
      element.classList.add(ACTIVE_CLASS);
      return;
    }

    // This animation uses the FLIP approach. You can read more about it at the link below:
    // https://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/

    // Calculate the dimensions based on the dimensions of the previous indicator
    const currentClientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (this.orientation === 'vertical') {
      const heightDelta = previousIndicatorClientRect.height / currentClientRect.height;
      const yPosition = previousIndicatorClientRect.top - currentClientRect.top;
      element.classList.add(NO_TRANSITION_CLASS);
      this._inkBarContentElement.style.setProperty('transform',
                                                   `translateY(${yPosition}px) scaleY(${heightDelta})`);
    } else {
      const widthDelta = previousIndicatorClientRect.width / currentClientRect.width;
      const xPosition = previousIndicatorClientRect.left - currentClientRect.left;
      element.classList.add(NO_TRANSITION_CLASS);
      this._inkBarContentElement.style.setProperty('transform',
                                                   `translateX(${xPosition}px) scaleX(${widthDelta})`);
    }

    // Force repaint before updating classes and transform to ensure the transform properly takes effect
    element.getBoundingClientRect();

    element.classList.remove(NO_TRANSITION_CLASS);
    element.classList.add(ACTIVE_CLASS);
    this._inkBarContentElement.style.setProperty('transform', '');
  }
}
```

Sounds simple enough. So I install this library in my app and use it like this:

```
<nav mat-oriented-nav-bar
     [tabPanel]="navPanel"
     orientation="vertical"
     color="accent">
  <a *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [id]="link.label"
     mat-oriented-link
     (click)="activeLink = link"
     [active]="activeLink === link"
     [routerLink]="link.href"
     routerLinkActive="active"><mat-icon>{{link.icon}}</mat-icon>{{link.label}}</a>
</nav>
```

I also had to add a provider in app.module due to angular complaining there was none:

```
...
providers: [MatTabNav, ...]
...
```

However, this throws `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toArray')` in angular material's _MatTabLinkBase, which MatTabLink is derived from.
The function is this:

```
 _handleFocus() {
   // Since we allow navigation through tabbing in the nav bar, we
   // have to update the focused index whenever the link receives focus.
   this._tabNavBar.focusIndex = this._tabNavBar._items.toArray().indexOf(this);
 }
```

As you can see in the definition of MatOrientedLink above, the link gets passed its container MatOrientedNav in the constructor, which will then be used in its parent class as property _tabNavBar. And MatTabNav contains this property, which then, MatOrientedNav should also contain:

```
@ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => MatTabLink), {descendants: true}) _items: QueryList<MatTabLink>;
```

Hence, this error means the MatOrientedNav is missing the _items property, which it should not. If I change the container element to <nav mat-tab-nav-bar ...>, the error does not show up.

Setting a breakpoint in the `MatOrientedLink` constructor in the dev tools and checking the `tabNavBar` attribute sent into the constructor I found that, while the dev tools claim it's a `MatTabNav` object, the object's native element contains the classes `'mdc-tab mat-mdc-tab-link mat-mdc-focus-indicator'`, i.e. the classes of the `MatTabLink` component, not the `MatTabNav` component, which means the `MatOrientedLink` constructor gets itself injected (or another object of its own class), instead of its container.
With the container element as <nav mat-tab-nav-bar ...> the element in the constructor is correctly showing the `MatTabNav` classes `'mat-mdc-tab-nav-bar mat-mdc-tab-header ng-tns-c3816625663-1'`, so it is the container being injected.

How is it possible the MatOrientedNav is not properly injected here?

The angular material source code to the nav bar can be found here but I can't find an explanation to this behaviour there: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/16.2.x/src/material/tabs/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.ts

Comment: Maybe you should provide a StackBlitz? From the example I would also expect it to work. Maybe the underlying problem is missing from your code example in the post.

Comment: @Wilt That would be quite some work I would rather avoid. The question is more of a fundamental matter anyway. How is it even possible that my injected MatOrientedNav, which presumably is a MatTabNav (I mean ... okay, I guess? It is derived at least), has the wrong elementRef? How is it possible the link element is even contained there? The elementRef in the nav component is correct, so it is the injection going fatally wrong here. How would I do the injection correctly? Something fundamental seems to be missing. And there isn't even anything else in my code related to that.